# Detect if the select box scroll bar has reached to bottom

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have a select dropdown and I want to load more options in it when the scroll bar reaches at bottom but could not do. I used the following code but this did not work for me

```
$(function () {
             var $win = $('#CouponProduct_0_id_brand');

             $win.scroll(function () {
                 if ($win.scrollTop() == 0)
                     alert('Scrolled to Page Top');
                 else if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop()
                                == $(document).height()) {
                     alert('Scrolled to Page Bottom');
                 }
             });
         });
```

Comment: I suggest you convert your select to a widget - there is not a safe way to detect what you are trying to detect

Answer (score -1):

[Found your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6428773/2260614)

Instead of automatically loading more list-items, I suggest placing a button users can tap to load more (but that's just my suggestion).[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9623793/2260614)

[Check out this pulgin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#infinite)

Comment: That defeat the purpose of dynamic html. Should not be post as answer if its only a suggestion?